# Azure Functions, NodeJS and Application Insights

Tags: node.js, azure-functions

I have written some simple functions and enabled `Application Insights`,

Its all showing as connected and I can see that's its tracking http statues, eg I get a failed request count and server response times etc.

[image]

I understand that I can add application insights to node with the following code

```
let appInsights = require("applicationinsights");
appInsights.setup("[your ikey]").start();
```

But I was hoping it would just work without this, I can see that the function is outputting logs when I use the log stream

[image]

But when I use app insights I don't see anything in any of the log tables

[image]

Do I need to add insights via code to my function or I am missing some secret config option.

Comment: Good day sir, did you mean that you wanna to enable application insights for your function written by nodejs without adding any code? If so, you can enable the app insights in the blade of your function. After that it will require you to create a new appinsight instance or choose an existing one. And I tried it, when I call the newly created httptrigger, I can get records in the `requests` table.https://i.stack.imgur.com/5arER.png

Comment: I can the requests just not the traces from the context or errors. But... I added the application insights node modules and recreated the app insights resource and it started to work eg it logged traces and full errors with full stack traces. I am not sure if recreated the application insights fixed it or adding the node modules

Comment: I shared some documents related and I think it's fine of your situation. If you have further questions, pls feel free to add comment here, thanks for your response sir :)

Answer (score 0):

That's also a good idea to add application insights module into your node project to achieve monitor feature for your function. Both code and codeless are good choices.

In my opinion, the biggest difference between code and codeless monitor is the [custom telemetry data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring?tabs=cmd#custom-telemetry-data). But I think in most scenarios, default information collected is enough for daily using, [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-functions) says:

> Application Insights collects log, performance, and error data, and
> automatically detects performance anomalies.

So I think it's ok for you when you could get traces and error messages after adding appinsights module and recreate a new appinsights instance. And you can also try to use codeless configuration I mentioned in the comment(azure portal-> your function written by nodejs-> Application insights-> enable-> create new resource)

Comment: I did this  *add insights moudle into your node project* and it did start to work, so I presume for `context.log` to work, it needs the node modules to be present but you don't need any code to setup app insights.

Comment: If you add insights module into your nodejs program, you need to add instrumentation key to your code, see [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/nodejs). If you don't  like to add any code into your program, you may refer to [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-web-apps?tabs=net). Azure function is also a kind of app service.